# How to prevent jQuery datepicker from popping up on initial page load but still scroll to datepicker textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-events

I have something similar to the following Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtDate").focus();
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
        ...
        autoOpen: false,
        ...
    });
});
```

I want to focus in on the textbox on page load without having the datepicker pop up. Currently the page loads with the datepicker already open.

I need to be able to have the page scroll to that textbox on page load and it would be nice for the *txtDate* textbox to have focus so that users can tab to the next input in the form easily.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
NOTE: must work in IE 8-10

Comment: Works in this example here. (google chrome)  http://jsfiddle.net/pQALk/  Is there more code that your not showing which is causing the issue?

Comment: `txtDate` does not seem to be a valid element.. Are you targeting an `id` or a `class`?

Comment: oops supposed to be id. i just changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var initialized = false;
$(function () {
    $("#txtDate").focus();
    $("#txtDate").blur(function(){
        if(!initialized){
            $("#txtDate").datepicker({
                autoOpen: false
            });    
            initialized = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/pQALk/3/

Comment: yea... oops i meant to put # signs in front of the element ids. yea i have autoOpen set to false too. and yes i need it to work in IE 8-10. I just updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery works:

```
$(function () {
    $(".txtDate").focus();
    setTimeout(function() {$(".txtDate").datepicker({
        autoOpen: false
    });},10);
});
```

It's a bit of a hack - added a delay of 0.01 seconds before binding the datepicker, so the focus happens before the datepicker is bound and so doesn't trigger the datepicker.
http://jsfiddle.net/pQALk/2/