# Datepicker pops up on first focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

The first input field of my form gains focus after a few miliseconds after document ready (in my case up to 50 ms). Then the datepicker pops up in case the first input field is a date.

What I need is to have focus on the first input field after the page loads and pop up the datepicker on focus event, but not immediately after the page loads. Which means if the first input element is a date, it gains focus and after I click on it the datepicker should show itself. Then all the other datepickers should pop up on focus. I need to do it that way so I wont have to loose and gain focus again.

```
<input data-calendar-format="dd.MM.yyyy">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[data-calendar-format]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });
});
```

Comment: what is it you want exactly?

Comment: Can you do some jsfiddle efforts?

Comment: The page loads. The first input field gains focus and has the cursor in it. After I click on it - without clicking out first the datepicker would show. All the other inputs with a datepicker would show the datepicker on focus.

Comment: Sounds a lot like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983172/how-to-prevent-jquery-datepicker-from-popping-up-on-initial-page-load-but-still?rq=1)

Comment: That does not solve my problem, because I dont want the element to loose focus before the datepicker shows. I also can not set timeout for the initialization to wait and detect the focus on a date element, because it wont be the same time for multiple clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `beforeShow` option to prevent the `datepicker` from opening. If the page just loaded `return false`. I have used time to determine whether the page just loaded; if you're going to use time find a time that suits your needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = Date.now();
    $('input[data-calendar-format]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        beforeShow: function() {
            if( Date.now() - dt < 51 ) {              
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $(':input').first().focus().on('click',function() {
        $(this).datepicker('show');
    });   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input data-calendar-format="dd.MM.yyyy">
```

Comment: Even in this case you have to loose focus and then gain it again.

Comment: @Lejla take a look at the updated version. .. Not that since you have a process that focuses on the first element after 50ms you do not need the `.first().focus()` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `showOn`property on the first datepicker to `button`, hide the button in your css and add an `autofocus` to your input field. Adding an additional `click` handler to the first input will help to open the datepicker, before clicking anywhere else.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[data-calendar-format]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOn: "button"
  });
  $('.more-datepickers').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showOn: "focus"
  });
  $('input[data-calendar-format]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).datepicker("show");   
  })
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input data-calendar-format="dd.MM.yyyy" autofocus />
<input class="more-datepickers">
<input class="more-datepickers">
```

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but you could have two initializations: one for all the datepickers, and another for the first datepicker (if it's the first element):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // all the datepickers that are not the first child
    $('input[data-calendar-format]:not(:nth-child(1))').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });

    // the first child if it's a datepicker
    $('input[data-calendar-format]:nth-child(1)').focus().datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    }).on("click", function() {
        // the field is focused, so we need to trigger datepicker to show the first time
        $(this).datepicker("show");
    });

});
```

Update: If the field is focused, you'll need to trigger the datepicker to show the first time. Added a `click` event to deal with that.

You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqjgk8y7/1/